How can I delete a file with FileOutputStream and not just its contents
I have the below code to delete a file I created with FileOutputStream, however it only seems to be deleting the contents of the file, and not the file itself.
I've tried following this to write my code below: Deleting files created with FileOutputStream
What do I need to do to delete the file and not just its contents?
val file = File("myFileName.txt")

    try {
        val fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream =
            context.openFileOutput(
                "myFileName.txt",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            )

        fileOutputStream.close()
        file.delete()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.d(
            "Error deleting file",
            "${e.localizedMessage}"
        )
    }


"I've tried following this to write my code below: Deleting files created with FileOutputStream" - specifically how did you change the code in order to try to follow that? What happened when you tried doing that, and how is that different from what you want?

Why would you create a filestream and open it just to close it and delete the file? I'd suggest that you change your question to How do I delete a file in Kotlin? to learn how to do it the right way.

This is not a pure Kotlin question. You're using Android methods, so I added the android tag.

The problem you're having is because you are referring to two different files:

File("myFileName.txt") is a file in your current working directory.
context.openFileOutput("myFileName.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) is a file associated with this Context's application package.

If you're creating the file through the context, you should also delete the file through the context:
context.deleteFile("myFileName.txt")

If, on the other hand, you want to create a file in the current working directory, then you should not use context but use the Kotlin methods of Path to write and delete the file. In particular, deleting like this:
path.deleteExisting()

will throw an IOException if it fails to delete, and you can then investigate the cause more easily than the old legacy File.delete method which just returns false and doesn't give a reason.

You can try this to create the file, write to it (or perform some other operation), and delete the file:
val file = File("C:\\foo.txt")

// Use FileOutputStream to write the content to the file
FileOutputStream(file).use { fos ->
    val content = "Hello World!".toByteArray()
    fos.write(content)
}

// Verify that the content is written to file
println(file.readText())

// Delete the file along with its contents
file.delete()
println(file.exists()) // false


Note the use method closes the stream resource: use - Kotlin.
